# member not found jquery on individual server

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, weblogic, load-balancing

We are using jQuery v1.8.2 for our application(used in IE 11) with a simple dropdown on the login page as shown below.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#mydropdown" ).selectmenu({ width : '125'});
});
```

The same application code is deployed on 2 weblogic servers e.g.

```
https://<server1 IP>.myapp.net/
https://<server2 IP>.myapp.net/
https://app.myapp.net/ (The load balancer URL)
```

We see the following results

- The dropdown appears fine on first server url and the load balancer
  url.
- But, with the second server url, we get the error 'Member Not
  Found'.
- It also works fine on the load balancer url even if the
  first server(where it is working) is shut down.
- Tried using meta tag "X-UA-Compatible", but no luck.

Couldn't figure out the problem on the second server. Any clues?

Comment: Are the two servers using the same source code or each running their own copy of jQuery? Do you see any other console errors when each page loads?

Comment: Hi Twisty, each server has their own copy of jQuery. On the second server, we get the error 'Member Not Found'.